# Error adding data from Form to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a form where it accepts 3 values Name, Weight, Breed and 2 values are dynamically generated, 1 is datatime and the other is Size which is calculated using weight. Once the Add button is clicked the data should be added to DataTable and displayed in GridView.

For the first input time its working fine... But if I fill the Form again then the GridView is losing the 1st row data and only the latest data is being displayed. I tried to rectify it by (!isPostback), but now it shows error "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."

Below is the code

```
public partial class Datatables : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                lblSatus.Text = string.Empty;
                prepare();
            }                   

            lblSatus.Text += "Outside postback pageload"+dtable.Columns.Count.ToString()+"<br>";
        }
        private void prepare()
        {
            if (dtable.Columns.Count == 0)
            {
                dtable.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(int));
                dtable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
                dtable.Columns.Add("Breed", typeof(string));
                dtable.Columns.Add("size", typeof(char));
                dtable.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
                lblSatus.Text += "DataTable Created with " + dtable.Columns.Count.ToString() + " Columns <br>";                       
            }                
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            AddDogData(txtName.Text,Convert.ToInt32(txtWeight.Text), txtBreed.Text);
            GridView1.DataSource = dtable;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            lblSatus.Text += "Added data to Datatable<br>";
        }   

        static DataRow AddDogData(string name,int weight,string breed)
        {
            return dtable.Rows.Add(weight, name, breed, GetSizeChar(weight), DateTime.Now);
        }

        static char GetSizeChar(int weight)
        {
            if (weight >= 100)
                return 'B';
            else if (weight > 50 && weight < 100)
                return 'M';
            else
                return 'S';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't dtable be static also?

Comment: @black baron static is not mandatory